# CSS Custom Font Not working

Tags: css, encoding, fonts, font-face, custom-font

I have installed new font in windows and now i want to use that font in my web as a custom font. In image below it will describe all of my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/GybED.png

[image]

Here is my Code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='uft-8' />
        <style type="text/css">
            @font-face {
                font-family: urdu;
                src: url(font/urdu/NOORIN01.TTF);
            }
            @font-face {
                font-family: eng;
                src: url(font/sansation_light.woff);
            }

            body{
                font-size:30px;
            }
            .urdu{font-family:'urdu';}
            .eng{font-family:'eng';}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class='urdu'>میں نے آپ کے مسئلے کو قتل کرنے جا رہا ہوں</div>
        <div>میں نے آپ کے مسئلے کو قتل کرنے جا رہا ہوں</div>
        <div class="eng">The quick and brown fox jump over the lazy dog.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

here are font files
http://speedy.sh/WdxpP/sansation-light.woff
http://speedy.sh/wEzZ6/NOORIN01.TTF

Comment: Does your inspector show that file as 200 okay or is there an error?

Comment: font/urdu/NOORIN01.TTF path is fine, and no error is there. I think encoding issue etc

Comment: i have provide code and font aswell so expert can test it themselves.

Comment: You have 'uft-8' as your charset. Should be UTF-8

Comment: i guess in html its doesn't matter because its insensitive. however i have checked it too, its doesn't solve the problem

Comment: those font links require someone to pay for the fonts, do you have a direct link to the fonts?

Comment: This might be the solution you are looking for or may direct you to the correct answer. I realize this is not aribic but the concept is similar. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246973/using-font-face-css-stylewith-an-arabic-font.

Comment: not paid font, you can select free download, not such a big file.

Comment: i tried to generate my font but it gives error that "font from other vendor can't be regenrate"

Answer (score 1):

The font is broken. I tested with the [NOORIN01.TTF](http://www.speedyshare.com/wEzZ6/NOORIN01.TTF) font available from the address specified and tested with the code in the question. This is what I see in Firefox console (on Win 7):

```
downloadable font: hdmx: Table discarded (font-family: "urdu" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
source: [...]
downloadable font: not usable by platform (font-family: "urdu" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:0)
source: file:///C:/Users/Jukka/Documents/Fonts/NOORIN01.TTF
```

Looking at the font in a font inspector, I notice that the characters are assigned to Private Use codepoints. This could “work” as such, but then the HTML content needs to contain those code points. And it apparently fails to work since some table in the font is broken.

The conclusion is: find another font.

Comment: this is urdu language standard font, do i need to create my own font for urdu, any method to show even a few character with existing font. How to proceed

Comment: @Wasim, I wonder what that standard might be. Anyway, finding a font suitable for a specific language is a different question, and off-topic at SO. Anyway, modern versions of Arial supports Urdu, and in general you can expect your visitor’s browsers to be able to render Urdu text even if you don’t do anything.